# Is there any new REST APIs to be used for IAV (Instant Account Verification)

Tags: rest, yodlee

REST API documentation is very confusing right now on the yodlee site, especially for the IAV features and the developer information (flows vs API references vs Integration Guide) does not seem to be current and coherent regarding IAV features vs new/old REST APis.

On the Integration Guide page:

https://developer.yodlee.com/API_Resources/Integration_Guide

there is a note saying:

> Yodlee Account Verification APIs use an earlier version of our API platform. Even though these APIs support standard REST and SOAP formats, the data model is different.

Can someone confirm the mess about the IAV documentation on the site and provide some guidance as to which APIs to use for IAV and which section of the site is current for IAV?

Answer (score 0):

Basically IAV is used for real time user account verification.
For verification Yodlee provides two services: Data Service and Matching Service.

Data service – Yodlee uses the credentials provided by the consumer to log in to the specified bank website and returns all verification information found for the accounts at that site. The Yodlee customer then performs the verification by using their own rules.

Matching service – The account matching is done at Yodlee’s end based on Yodlee’s own matching algorithm.

REST IAV API flow: https://developer.yodlee.com/Account_Verification/API_Flow

Comment: For IAV features: https://developer.yodlee.com/Instant_Account_Verification(IAV)_API/IAV_Services_Guide/IAV_Features
And you can try these APIs in our swagger: https://developer.yodlee.com/api-dashboard